# HTML/CSS: increase border size without affect the height

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a border bottom of 1px for each column. On row hover i want set the border to 2px, see the example:

```css
tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

tr:hover td {
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

On hover, the row increases in height and moves the next row 1px down.

Can I increase the border size without affecting the height?

Comment: Why would you want your border not to increase the height of your row in the first place? The border needs to expand in some way in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `border-image` like below:

```css
tr td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(to top,grey 1px,transparent 0) 2;
}

tr:hover td {
  border-image:linear-gradient(to top,red 2px,transparent 0) 2;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or the same gradient as background:

```css
tr td {
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top,grey 1px,transparent 0);
}

tr:hover td {
  background:linear-gradient(to top,red 2px,transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can decrease bottom padding which will decrease the height of td and it will not affect your td height.

```css
tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

tr:hover td {
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
   padding-bottom: 0px;**strong text**
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outline` to achieve the same but outline applies to the [whole element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)

So you can use `box-shadow` to create an outline on one side. Like `outline`, `box-shadow` does not change the size of the box model.

```css
tr td {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000 inset;
}

tr:hover td {
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 #f00 inset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use box-shadow, to create a border-like style that dosen´t effekt the height of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by setting a specific height and setting `box-sizing:border-box`

```css
tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  height:30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

tr:hover td {
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

when you increase the size your line become more height (because of his new border)
if you want only increase the height without to change the size of the line do such:

tr:hover td {
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
height:your privious heigt-1
}

Comment: Calculations, however, are not able in CSS are they now? So that would be a JavaScript solution.